# Java: Using diagnostics.getDiagnostics() to find errors

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I am creating a compiler program using java, I have it compiling java files, and i have it finding out what error happened and on which line it happened on. My question is that when it is printing out this information i am getting a load of `///////////` in the middle of the output and I dont understand why this is!

My output is

```
Error on line 4 in ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////.java:4: error: class ToCompileTwo is public, should be declared in a file named ToCompileTwo.java
public class ToCompileTwo {
```

this is the code i am using to get this display

```
for (Diagnostic diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()) {
            System.out.format("Error on line %d in %s", diagnostic.getLineNumber(), diagnostic);
        }
```

**EDIT**

I managed to fix this, the following method is what was creating the `////////`

```
protected DynamicJavaSourceCodeObject(String name, String code) {
    super(URI.create("string:///" + name.replaceAll(".", "/") + Kind.SOURCE.extension), Kind.SOURCE);
    this.qualifiedName = name;
    this.sourceCode = code;
}
```

I changed the second line to

```
super(URI.create("string:///" + name.replaceAll("\\\\", "/") ), Kind.SOURCE);
```

This fixed the problem

Comment: Can we see the source of Diagnostic's toString() method?

Comment: How do you generate the source you are compiling, specifically, what kind of file manager do you use? The slashes are the "filename".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `name.replaceAll(".", "/")` you replace all by `/`. [ReplaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) take a regex as first parameter so you match ALL characters with `.` and replace them with `/`.

Replace your statement with :

```
name.replaceAll("\\.", "/")
```

`\\.` : stand for the character dot.

Comment: when i change it to that i get the following error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 12: string:///C:\projects\Compiler\Files To Be Organised\Assignment1\111223361\Assignment1_111223361/java.java

Comment: @HipHipArray You should use `/` instead of ` \ ` . You can use `.replace("\\", "/")` for that.

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand your last comment

Comment: ya i noticed that alright, and made the change, an error was also because one of the folders that it was in had spaces in the name which it was having problems with, but sorted it now :)